# What is pdflatex -shell-escape file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, convert, button

Tex Live 2018 Windows.

I was told this is part of creating image files from latex instead of PDF files. What is what is pdflatex -shell-escape file? Where is it? How do I access it?

Comment: You probably need to be a lot more specific about what exactly it is you are yoing and why you are interested in ` pdflatex -shell-escape file` it can be very dangerous, so better if we know more about what you are doing.

Comment: I need a jpg or png output to put math figures from latex into a blog without them being too low-pixel

Comment: Is this formulas or figures? If its the latter, I wouldn't bother making images, use mathjax or katex to render the formulas in the browser

Comment: `-shell-escape` is not a file but option of `pdflatex` program that make enable `\write18` syntax. `\write18` allow to execute shell command, for instance to create or convert files as in your case. Default this feature is restricted because that may not safe if you not sure what you do.

Comment: Figures. I already have mathjax set up, I may wind up just learning a different software for the figures. Thanks